# Create a hierarchy from an array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, hierarchy

I've an array as follows.

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'parent' => 'Bigboss',
        'middle' => 'Technicians',
        'child' => 'Players'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'parent' => 'Company',
        'middle' => 'Manager',
        'child' => 'Employees'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'parent' => 'Bigboss',
        'middle' => 'Manager',
        'child' => 'Workers'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'parent' => 'Company',
        'middle' => 'Techinical Lead',
        'child' => 'Employees'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'parent' => 'Bigboss',
        'middle' => 'Workers',
        'child' => 'Employees'
    )
);
```

I want this array in hierarchy way like

```
parent
=> middle
    => child
parent
=> middle
    => child
```

Exactly like as follows.

```
array(
    'Biggboss' => array(
        'Technicians' => array(
            0 => 'Players'
        ),
        'Manager' => array(
            0 => 'Workers'
        ),
        'Workers' => array(
            0 => 'Employees'
        )
    ),
    'Company' => array(
        'Manager' => array(
            0 => 'Employees'
        ),
        'Techinical Lead' => array(
            0 => 'Employees'
        )
    )
);
```

if anyone could solve it would be more appreciated.

Comment: @hey sanganabasu, ask Mass to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this works...

```
$input = array(
    0 => array(
        'parent' => 'Bigboss',
        'middle' => 'Technicians',
        'child' => 'Players'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'parent' => 'Company',
        'middle' => 'Manager',
        'child' => 'Employees'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'parent' => 'Bigboss',
        'middle' => 'Manager',
        'child' => 'Workers'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'parent' => 'Company',
        'middle' => 'Techinical Lead',
        'child' => 'Employees'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'parent' => 'Bigboss',
        'middle' => 'Workers',
        'child' => 'Employees'
    )
);

$output = array();

foreach($input as $key => $value){
    if(!isset($output[$value['parent']])){ 
        $output[$value['parent']] = array();
    }
    $output[$value['parent']][$value['middle']] = array($value['child']);
}

print_r($output);
```

If you want to allow multiple values in the last dimension then change:

```
$output[$value['parent']][$value['middle']] = array($value['child']);
```

to

```
$output[$value['parent']][$value['middle']][] = $value['child'];
```